# Get Instagram emails through Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, restfb

I have an application, that obtains user's Facebook access token with **instagram_basic** permission and gets information about the user's Facebook and Instagram pages.

I am able to get Instagram account ids, using graph explorer

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts%3Ffields%3Dinstagram_business_account&version=v3.2
```

By the following request

```
me/accounts?fields=id,access_token,name,link,instagram_business_account
```

Using restfb library I am able to get all information about the user. The full list of fields: `

https://restfb.com/javadoc-2/com/restfb/types/instagram/IgUser.html`

Also, I am able to set email for my Instagram account through Instagram and though Facebook page (provided, the Instagram account is bound to the Facebook page).
However, cannot find any of these emails in the responses if Facebook Graph API, neither documented, nor non-documented. Could you please point me the way how to get those emails?

Comment: I think you already tried the metadata query parameter?

Comment: @Norbert not sure what parameter you are talking about. Is that parameter listed in the docs?